# Best way to speed up PyMongo loop

Tags: python, database, mongodb, performance, pymongo

I'm currently using a MongoDB database where I'm storing product data. I'm currently using a for loop of around ~50 IDs, and with each iteration, I'm searching for the ID and if the ID doesn't exist, I'm adding it, and if it exists and another column is a specific value, I'll run a function.

```
for id in ids:
  value = db.find_one({"value": id})
  if value:
    # It checks for some other columns here using both the ID and the return value
  else:
    # It adds the ID and some other information to the database
```

The problem here is that this is incredibly inefficient. When searching around for other ways to do this, all results show how to get a list of the results, but I'm not sure how this would be implemented in my scenario since I'm running functions and checks with each result and ID.

Thank you!

Comment: You don't show the details, but I'm wondering why a single `update_many` won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve by doing only one `find` request.
And in a second time, add all the documents in DB. Maybe with an `insert_many` ?

```
value = db.find({"value": {"$in": ids}})
for value in values:
    # It checks for some other columns here using both the ID and the return
    ids.remove(value.id)

# Do all your inserts
# with a loop
for id in ids:
    df.insert(...)
# or with insert_many
db.insert_many(...)
```